# A word for 'being secretly watched' by someone.

Tags: word-request

Let's say I daily offer water to one specific holy plant. One day i'm in a converstion with my new neighbour for the first time ever since he came(after many months).

> ME: I'm quite religious. 
>   HE: Yeah, I've seen you offer water daily to that plant.
>   ME: Really? I didn't know I was 'being secretly watched.'

I'd like to replace 'secretly watched' with another one word that can imply the same meaning. 
It could be of any form. Please feel free to re-phrase my line, if needed. I feel like there **is** a one word for that. 
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247705/a-single-word-for-secretly-watching-your-crush

Comment: @fixer1234well...that site did not have any words that would fit in my context. Maybe the situation is same but here I'd like to playfully tell the guy that 'I didn't know I was a victim of his furtive glances...'

Comment: A side note. In English, we normally "water a plant" or "give the plant some water". We normally reserve the verb **offer** for sentient beings, for creatures that can accept or refuse the offer. Plants are not included in that category in western cultures.

Comment: @TRomano Thankyou for pointing that out. I did consider that fact before but the I came across **offering water** while surfing the net, so I thought it would be universal.. If it's really not acceptable please feel free to kindly edit my question:)

Comment: The verb **offer** is not unacceptable here; **offer** is in keeping with the notion that the plant is holy. I only wanted to point out the words we use when speaking of typical plants of the secular variety.

Answer (score 4):

The standard answer would be

> I didn't know I was '*being spied on / upon.*'

for something not as accusatory, one might ask

> Have you been spying on me?

with a smile.

Answer (score 2):

As user178049 suggested, **spied on** (spy: [To watch or observe secretly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spied+on))

Another would be that you were **surveilled** (surveillance: [close watch kept over someone or something (as by a detective)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surveillance))

Comment: Thankyou, but I was kind of hoping fo a word which has a **playful** and **mischevious** tone to it rather than accusing one. That's why I'm doubtful to consider either of these words.

Comment: @Nikki, Surveilled is definitely not playful, by spying is sometimes used as a playful term.  I'll have to think about potential other words.

Comment: @Nikki, "secretly admired" or "secret admirer" would be positive and could imply watching someone in secret (it could also just mean holding someone in high esteem but not telling anyone).

Answer (score 2):

> I didn't realize I was being watched.

is idiomatic, as you have it in the title to your question.

If you want to introduce an element of mischief ("I'd like to playfully tell the guy that I didn't know I was a victim of his furtive glances... I was kind of hoping for a word which has a playful and mischevious tone to it")

> I didn't know you were *looking me over*.
>
> I'm not sure the plant likes to be *ogled*. It is a holy plant, after all.